# Cannot resolve symbol after importing GitHub Project to IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

So I'm working on a project that my friend had started. However, for some reason, after importing it from GitHub for the first time, there are hundreds of errors everywhere. It's a MineCraft plugin, and things such as 'Listener', 'EventHandler', '.getPlayer', are all getting 'Cannot resolve symbol'.

I took some screenshots, not sure if they will help in resolving any of this:
https://i.gyazo.com/81c21c5da19d6be1235870a4e213056d.png
https://gyazo.com/c692a04e3d598fe20de0ad79000cc409

Answer (score 0):

Based on your screenshots, the project is referencing jars that IntelliJ can't find. In the project structure dialog, click on "problems" at the bottom and you should get a list of issues. Depending on the type of project you might need manually download the libraries.